# Передача аргументов командной строки

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте! Только начинаю изучать С++ и ещё не освоилась в Visual Studio. Хочу программе передать аргументы (строку, например), как это сделать в Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо всем:) ответ на мой вопрос на рисунке.

Answer (score 1):

> Чтобы задать аргументы командной строки для отладки.
>
> 1. Выбрав проект в **Обозревателе решения**, в меню **Проект** выберите команду **Свойства**.
> 2. Перейдите на вкладку **Отладка**.
> 3. В поле **Аргументы командной строки** введите аргументы командной строки, которые будут использоваться.

[Практическое руководство. Установка параметров запуска для отладки приложения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/1ktzfy9w.aspx).